# svelte-navigator render route and its parent

Tags: svelte

I would like to render a route and a subroute (if that is possible). Actually router is

```js
<Router>
  <Route path="/*" component={Layout}>
    <Route path="pvp" component={Pvp} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

If I navigate to **/pvp** the **Layout** component is correctly rendered but the **Pvp** does not render at all. I'm probably looking to reproduce the [Outlet concept of react-router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#nested-routes). Is that possible in any way ?